# Persistence frameworks and unique save

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I have a simple question.  In my limited experience persistence frameworks appear to avoid a "unique-save" method.  For example, I may have a Zip code object that is going to be persisted in a "ZIP_CODE" table.  I would like the codes in the table to be unique, but the table dynamic (growing with new unique codes).  It seems that the "convention" for processing such data is to search the table to see if a new zip code is already there, If it is I can use it in say a many-to-one mapping for maybe an address object.  If it is not, I can save it and then use it. In a sense this is a two step process: read, save which needs to be managed in my application code.  As an alternative, this functionality could be built within the persistence framework so that I could call a single unique save method that returned the required object.  It doesn't appear that this functionality is generally supported - not sure why.  I guess I could be missing something really obvious here!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "unique-save". Do you mean "find if exists and create otherwise"?

Comment: Yes, apologies if I was not clear!

Comment: Well, the only two options would be to check and insert if not present, or to attempt to insert and get an error back if already present. If it's probably going to be there (as in the case of ZIP codes), the first seems a lot more efficient. Just package this into a method and call that?

Comment: In one application I have there are maybe 50 objects like this and I do have such methods.  I guess the question relates more to why this is not a standard part of most frameworks (I think Hibernate has a saveOrUpdate method) but not so the others?

Comment: I recommend to mark the field as unique (`@Column(unique=true)`) and surround your `insert` with a `try-catch` block. Whenever it fails you'll know that the value already exists in the table. I think that this is a more "maintainable" coding way.